# Backup Options in GCP Data Catalog

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am doing a PoC to use Data Catalog to maintain metadata of tables in BG.  As part of it, I am looking for options to take backup of the meta data stored in Data catalog, so that I can restore it in case of loses.

Has anyone tried this? is there an option to backup the Metadata from Data Catalog?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google support, there is no built-in way to backup the data that we put into Data Catalog.  The have created [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152825105).

Since we use the CLI to do most of our work, our workaround is to backup all the CLI commands that we use to create the tag templates and attach them to assets.  In an outage, we could replay all the commands with a different region parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this open source Python CLI:
[datacatalog-util](https://github.com/mesmacosta/datacatalog-util)

That has options to export your Data Catalog resources. You have options to export Tags, Tag Templates and Filesets to CSV files.

If you want to test it out, there are Cloud Shell walkthrough tutorials available in the same repo.